# Vietnam e-visa: exit Point differing from entry Point

Tags: visas, vietnam, e-visas

While filling out the Vietnam e-visa application, they ask the applicant to fill out the intended entry airport and the intended exit airport. At the time of filling this form, I filled in the same airport for both (Hanoi).

However, since that point of time, I have decided to travel to Ho Chi Minh and fly out from there. My question is, can I fly out of an airport which I did not list as my intended departure point?

I have received my visa, it only has a field where they have put down "Permitted to enter through: Hanoi Airport"
There is no mention of an exit point.

Can I use this visa?

Thank you!

Comment: Late to the game, but for those who find this on Google, you CANNOT leave on international flights with an evisa from airports not listed as evisa approved. (Ie Da Lat). Learned this the hard way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wanted to share my experience -

The only thing they care about is your entry point. You can exit the country from any other international airport (or sea/land port) which can process e-visas. The exit point entered in the visa application process is not binding.

To a certain extent, I also feel that the entry point is not binding either - as long as you enter the country through a port which can process an e-visa, you should be good. However, it's probably not worth risking it and you should enter the country through where you said you would.

Answer (score 2):

Visa on arrival works if you arrive at any of the five international airports: Tan Son Nhat (in Ho Chi Minh City); Noi Bai (in Hanoi), Da Nang (in Da Nang) and Nha Trang City - Cam Ranh Airport . There is no problem with switching between these five airports.

https://www.myvietnamvisa.com/faqs.html

Answer (score 2):

I just came back from a week-long trip to Vietnam. I wanted to share that I had my entry point on my eVisa as Ho Chi Minh Seaport instead of the airport and I had no problem at immigration. But I had done an additional VOA approval letter from an online site for $6 (the cheapest one I could get) just in case. But I didn't need it because they didn't have any problem with my eVisa.